# Fiddler2 doesnt capture Java traffic

Tags: java, proxy, fiddler, traffic

I'm trying to capture some native Java application HTTPS traffic using Fiddler2 as a proxy. To do so, I followed [this article on asjava.com](http://www.asjava.com/tools/capture-http-https-traffic-from-java-programs-with-fiddler/).

Here is what I have done in fact:

1. Install and configure Fiddler2 as a proxy: the configuration is identical as mentioned in the article I referred to.
2. Export fiddler certificate and import into appropriate JRE/JDK. I'm using an adapted version of Eclipse for developing, so I took a look to **Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's**, checked the path and imported it like:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias fiddlercert -file C:\fiddlerRoot.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk6\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
   ```
3. In my Java application to consider/test proxy settings I wrote a method:

   ```
   public boolean getCookieForUser(String username, String passwd, String system) {
       try {
           DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           try {
               System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
               System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
               HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(system + ":443/irj/portal");
               List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
               nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_user", username));
               nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", passwd));
               nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_authscheme", "default"));
               httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               EntityUtils.consume(entity);
               for(Cookie cookie:httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies()){
                   if(cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("MYSAPSSO2")){
                       ApplicationStateController.get()
                              .setSessionCoockie(cookie.getValue());
                       httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                       return getMandantForUser(username, passwd, system);
                   }
               }
           } finally {
               httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
           }
       } catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return false;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
4. Afterwards I start my Java Application from Eclipse and try a login (run the method `getCookieForUser`). This works well and the login works. Indeed, Fiddler is not showing the login request, I don't see anything at all.

What could go wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please format the code so it doesn't require scrolling. For example, http and https both are need to get help. Also your comment at the top doesn't add anything.

Comment: >Please format the code so it doesn't require scrolling.                                     Sorry,

Comment: Sorry, struggeling with scrolling, getting only the horizontal one away, no idea how to remove the vertical. May I ask you what do you mean with you need both protocols? Source is hardcoded to 443, so means its always a https request. My first sentence, I hope you meant that comment at the top, just means: I have written a Java application that causes https requests to a public server. What Im trying to do is to capture them with Fiddler2. Thank you for your friendly support

Comment: Remove comments. Remove http or https assignment lines.

Comment: You mean like current?

Comment: Yes! Also, if you could reduce your problem to the simplest complete code, you will get an answer quicker.

Comment: You are right, I simplified the source. In fact my expectation is: as soon HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost); happens, Fiddler has to capture some traffic. Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question a bit, to get the formatting right (like numbered lists are formatted well when you start with `1. ` without the parenthesis). I indented the inner parts of your code, and improved some grammar fixes. I think you should still edit a bit point 4: it looks strange to see *"This works well ... Indeed ... I don't see anything at all"*. This should be separated better. Good luck!